# How to make an area chart if a condition is true otherwise make a line chart?

Tags: charts, d3.js, conditional-statements

I am working with D3.JS to create a dashboard where the user can select from a list the number of variables to plot. If the user selects one or two variables, I want to create an area chart. If the user selects more than two variables, then I want to create only the edges of the area chart (i.e. line chart). I know no changes are needed in the code that creates the line chart. How can I add a conditional statement to the portion of the code that plots the area chart?

My data has the following form:

```
entries = [ { "key":"variable A", "value":[..] }, { "key":"variable B", "value":[..] } ]
```

I created a "for" to iterate through the objects and count how many variables were chosen by the user. The number of variables to plot are stored in "count"

```
focus.selectAll("path.area")
    .data(entries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", function (d) { return ( areasFocus(d.value) )})
    .style("fill", function (d) { return ( color(d.key) ) });
```

I have tried to replace the last two sentences with

```
.attr("d", function (d) { return (count<=2? areasFocus(d.value):areasFocus() )})
.style("fill", function (d) { return (count<=2? color(d.key) : color()) });
```

However, I get an error in the console telling me "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and the code breaks.

I suspect the problem is in the conditional statement.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is in the entries variable doesn't contain length property. Seems like you would like to get the length of some array / list from and object that is not an array / list.

Comment: You were right thanks! I did fix the problem of counting the number of elements in an object. The problem of how to create an area chart based on a condition still persists...

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the problem was in the if sentence, when the condition is false I needed to do "nothing". My mistake was to call the ares.Focus() with no arguments.